# CoreData model objects in ARC uses retain

Tags: core-data, automatic-ref-counting

When I create the model objects for my entity in CoreData in ARC mode, it generates retain instead or strong. So does retain work and compiles in ARC mode also? I thought in ARC mode we cannot use release, autorelease and retain keywords?

Comment: hmm this is surprising, no response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that it generates a `@property` declaration like this?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *object;
```

The `retain` property attribute means `strong` under ARC.

[4.1.1. Property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property)

Comment: That's great, but doesn't really answer the question, I like this guy have created a project using ARC, and upon adding Core Data into the mix, the NSManagedObjects are being generated with properties that use retain, not strong. While this shouldn't be legal in an ARC project unless otherwise specified as being non ARC section of the project, this is a strange occurrence. It should be expected to use strong not retain, or at least the compiler should complain that it doesn't match ARC rules... Any other thoughts

Comment: ARC doesn't ban the use of the `retain` keyword. It bans the use of the `retain` selector.  Keywords and selectors are totally different.  See §7.1.1 of the document I linked.

Answer (score 4):

Please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036821/662605

The gist of it is that if you `@synthesize` your properties, then the code generated under the hood will rely on the `retain` type (`retain`, `assign`, `copy`).

Generated Managed Object subclasses use `@dynamic` not `@synthesize`, all this stuff is happening magically for you, so actually, although it's confusing, the `retain` keyword isn't being used it would seem, therefore the ARC isn't complaining... I'm pretty sure that's it.

Although I did try to swap the implementation to use `@synthesize` and still didn't get errors, but I think we could be onto something with that answer on the link

Any other insights would be nice.